# WPF window content as content of another window

Tags: c#, wpf

i need to show my window as inside Tab of another window and i do it using the following

```
 var childWindowEditor = new MainWindow();   //window to embed
 object content = childWindowEditor.Content; //take out the content of the window to embed
 childWindowEditor.Content = null;
 EditorTab.Content = content;                //just a tab in a tabbed group
```

its working fine, but the problem is what if i wanted to access the functions of the window class?

i know tha i should create it as user control, but is there a solution without having to create the content of that window as a user control?

would casting the content to the window that i got the content from work?

Comment: You shouldn't reuse visuals. It is much easier to re-create them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `MVVM` pattern. Your `ViewModel` would be the `DataContext` of `childWindowEditor`. So you could simply do something like

```
EditorTab.DataContext = childWindowEditor.DataContext;
```

And that's it. I really recommend you to use `MVVM`. It makes your life much easier.

Answer (score 0):

You may use Pages and frames to display pages.

Add the frame on tab like this:

`<TabItem>
     <Frame Name="Frame1"></Frame>
 </TabItem>`

Show page inside frame:

`Frame1.Content = new MyPage1();`